Enviar los valores de unas variables desde un ESP32 como Access Point a la web que genera sin tener que recargarla entera
Quiero configurar my Esp32 con el movil (a traves de una pagina web generada por el Esp32), tras pulsar un pulsador conectado al Esp32. Hasta ahi, bien. He seguido el ejemplo del ide de arduino WiFiAccessPoint. He creado una pagina web y envio datos al Esp32 cuando le doy al boton "incrementar numero" o "decrementar numero". Con ello consigo que unas variables de mi Esp32 varien del 0 al 9. El problema es que tengo en una parte muy concreta de la pantalla en la pagina web, dentro de una tabla el valor a mostrar (0) . La pregunta es cómo envio el valor de esa variable de mi ESP32 a la pagina web para que solo se modifique esa parte y no volver a mostrar la pagina web entera de nuevo???

Configura una URL en el ESP32 que sólo devuelva el valor deseado. En la página, coloca un javascript que llama a esa URL, obtenga el valor y actualice el campo.
